# How do I render a specific part of the viewport?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, 3d-view

How can I render a specific spot in the render mode like this?

[image: example]

I want to know how to render a specific part of the scene I am rendering in the view port and is this still possible in blender 2.81?
If so please tell me. I have tried everything and still cant figure it out.
I know its a really stupid question but I really want to know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The functionality is called [Render region](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/navigate/regions.html#render-region). Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> and then draw a rectangle around the area you want to render.

Remove the region with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>